# Failed To Authenticate To NPS Server

Tags: windows-server-2019, radius, nps

I am running an NPS Server on my Windows Server 2019 of my network. I use it to authenticate into my Cisco C9300 switches as an administrator to work on them. Recently I am unable to login as it says I am not authenticated. Here is a copy of the NPS log I get when I try to SSH into the switch.

```
<Event>
<Timestamp data_type="4">12/14/2020 14:42:20.610</Timestamp>
<Computer-Name data_type="1">RADIUS-SERVER</Computer-Name>
<Event-Source data_type="1">IAS</Event-Source>
<User-Name data_type="1">user</User-Name>
<NAS-IP-Address data_type="3">192.168.0.10</NAS-IP-Address>
<Client-IP-Address data_type="3">192.168.0.10/Client-IP-Address>
<Client-Vendor data_type="0">0</Client-Vendor>
<Client-Friendly-Name data_type="1">SWITCHA01</Client-Friendly-Name>
<Proxy-Policy-Name data_type="1">NPS-Cisco</Proxy-Policy-Name>
<Provider-Type data_type="0">1</Provider-Type>
<SAM-Account-Name data_type="1">DOMAIN\user</SAM-Account-Name>
<Fully-Qualifed-User-Name data_type="1">DOMAIN\user</Fully-Qualifed-User-Name>
<Authentication-Type data_type="0">1</Authentication-Type>
<Class data_type="1">311 1 192.168.0.15 12/14/2020 17:46:50 8</Class>
<Packet-Type data_type="0">1</Packet-Type>
<Reason-Code data_type="0">0</Reason-Code>
</Event>
<Event>
<Timestamp data_type="4">12/14/2020 14:42:20.610</Timestamp>
<Computer-Name data_type="1">RADIUS-SERVER</Computer-Name>
<Event-Source data_type="1">IAS</Event-Source>
<Class data_type="1">311 1 192.168.0.15 12/14/2020 17:46:50 8</Class>
<Authentication-Type data_type="0">1</Authentication-Type>
<Client-IP-Address data_type="3">192.168.0.10</Client-IP-Address>
<Client-Vendor data_type="0">0</Client-Vendor>
<Client-Friendly-Name data_type="1">INSTRU-SWITCHA01</Client-Friendly-Name>
<Proxy-Policy-Name data_type="1">NPS-Cisco</Proxy-Policy-Name>
<Provider-Type data_type="0">1</Provider-Type>
<SAM-Account-Name data_type="1">DOMAIN\user</SAM-Account-Name>
<Fully-Qualifed-User-Name data_type="1">DOMAIN\user</Fully-Qualifed-User-Name>
<Packet-Type data_type="0">3</Packet-Type>
<Reason-Code data_type="0">16</Reason-Code>
</Event>
```

NPS Server is configured to us PAP as authentication at the moment to just see if I can get in but it keeps giving me Reason Code 16 which is un-authentication. What can I do to get back into my switches as admin with my domain admin account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing I found the issue. I moved the NPS from a Domain Controller to a Member Server. Do to rights assignments I was unable to log into the switch with my Domain Controller credentials because they are not allowed on be logged onto the Member Server the NPS was running on. I am still able to set any other group but that one to authenticate using NPS as long as it doesn't violate the User Rights Assignment.

I never thought they would be mutually exclusive but apparently they are.